# angularjs not redirecting on route

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am using angular.
I have defined a HTML file where i have given 2 links and on app.js i am defining the route.
But when i click on the link provided in html file, it is not redirecting.

Below is my html file and app.js file:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/javascript/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="../public/javascript/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/javascript/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../routes/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div >
    <a ui-sref="login">Login</a>
    <a ui-sref="register">Register</a>

<div ui-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.js:

```
 angular.module('test', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('register',
                {
                    templateUrl: '../partials/register.html',
                    controller: 'registration'
                });
            $routeProvider.when('login',
                {
                templateUrl: '../partials/login.html',
                controller: 'login'
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-sref is connected to ui-router (an alternative router for angular) and you are using angular-route in the routing. Use ng-href instead and your links should be written like `ng-href="#/login"` and `ng-href="#/register"` and your corresponding when routes should be `$routeProvider.when('/register',...` etc.

Comment: Its working fine now. But its not showing anything when it redirects to register/login page

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#/login">Login</a>
```

use this kind of routing `ui-serf` for ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router